# C++ class instances returned by value not acting like rvalues

Tags: c++

I had an interesting typo in some code the other day which led to a lengthy and frustrating debugging session, before I finally noticed the stray character on a much earlier line.  The issue was that I had a stray '-' in my code, which the compiler was turning into a call to unary `.operator-()` on a member variable many lines further down in the code (below some mid-function comment blocks), and was then performing an assignment into the temporary variable holding the result of that `operator-()` call, which I had intended to actually go into the member variable itself.  Net result: it was as if the assignment wasn't being performed at all, because it was silently being stored into a temporary.

I've simplified the issue into a minimum viable code demonstration, here, which generates no compile warnings or errors on either modern gcc or modern clang (but is untested in MSVC):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

class foo
{
public:

    int x;

    foo(): x(0) {}
    foo( int x_in ): x(x_in) {}
    foo operator-() const { return foo(-x); }
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    foo a( 10 );
    foo b( 20 );

    a = b;
    printf( "a: %d\n", a.x ); // a: 20

    a = foo( 10 );

    {
    }- // oops

    a = b;  // assigns the value '20' into the temporary storage holding '-a'
    printf( "a: %d\n", a.x ); // a: 10

    return 0;
}
```

My feeling is that the parsed '-a' should be treated as an rvalue, as it would be if 'a' was defined as an int rather than as a class, and the attempted assignment should generate a compile error, but it doesn't seem to do that in practice.

My first thought about how to guard against this was to change the function signature from `foo operator-() const` to `const foo operator-() const`, so at least compilers will complain if I try to assign a value to a generated temporary again.  Does anybody have a better solution, here, or an argument that it's *not* an issue I should be guarding against?

Comment: I would have expected this would at least create a warning, since you are assigning to a _rvalue_.

Comment: @paddy Agreed, which is why I asked the question;  the lack of warning or error, even when compiling with `-Wall` surprised me quite a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if 'a' was defined as an int rather than as a class, and the attempted assignment should generate a compile error

Class types behave differently with build-in types in this case, the copy assignment operator is allowed to be called on the temporary object here.

As you said, you can change the return type of `operator-` to `const foo`. Or you can [qualify](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#ref-qualified_member_functions) the copy assignment operator (and move assignment operator if necessary) with lvalue-reference (since C++11) to prevent assignment on rvalues.

```
class foo
{
public:

    int x;

    foo(): x(0) {}
    foo( int x_in ): x(x_in) {}
    foo operator-() const { return foo(-x); }

    foo& operator=(const foo&) & = default;
};
```

Comment: In the real codebase the problem happened with a class representing a 3D vector, so there are actually quite a lot of functions provided which modify the object.  I imagine that you would similarly need to lvalue-ref-qualify operator+=, operator*=, operator-=, and operator/=.  In fact, probably every non-const member function would probably need it.  Marking all returned value types as 'const' might actually be lower intrusion in the codebase.

Comment: Is there a use case for this? The difference in behavior to built-in types makes me think the design decision was deliberate. (The cases that come to my mind like chained assignments or complex expressions always assign to either an lvalue or create new objects, so they don't apply.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Copy assignment operator is a member function too. There're just no ways to prevent member functions being called on rvalues before C++11.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't declare any copy/move constructor/assignment operator, they will be implicitly provided to you by the compiler in the form:

```cpp
T::T(const T&);
T::T(T&&);
T& T::operator=(const T&);
T& T::operator=(T&&);
```

Howard Hinnant has an excellent slide presentation, which explains the rules. It's called [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Move Semantics](https://www.slideshare.net/ripplelabs/howard-hinnant-accu2014). Slide 30 has the final result.

In your example, these operators will work on both l- and r-value references, which is why it compiles with no errors.

To avoid assignment to r-values, you can declare your own (defaulted) versions with l-value ref-qualifier, thus preventing the compiler from providing implicitly declared ones.

So, if your case it could be something like this:

```cpp
class foo
{
public:

    ...

    foo& operator=(const foo&) & = default;
    foo& operator=(foo&&) & = default;
};
```

*You shouldn't have to make any other changes to your code.*

Full example on [`coliru`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45d453f1093dd9f7).

Look ma, no assignment.